# Old style navigation without using Frames/iFrames

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, html

I have a website with 1000+ pages, and want to make it easy to navigate by providing a three level navigation panel on the left side, with the page corresponding to the last level navigation item on the right pane. The navigation pane will look like:

Country -> State -> County

When I click on a specific county, it should load the content on the right pane. The page should not reload, only the content in the right pane should change. I need the menu selection to be preserved, so that the user need not select country and state every time while browsing county pages.

This would have been an easy task with old frames but I understand it is not to be used in HTML5. I am not supposed to use iFrames as well. What do you recommend as the best method here?

My page is hosted on Wordpress, any compatible solution will help.

Thanks
Uri

Comment: Can we guess your code? *If so, we'd sell your code.*

Comment: Sounds like you want a [single page app](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wordpress+single+page+application)

Comment: Thanks Stuartd. Your pointer helps!